# How to fix warnings while building signed APK with pro-guard enabled?

Tags: android

I am enabling pro-guard in app level gradle build, but I am not able to build signed APK, I am getting warnings so What I need to add in Proguard rules?

I am getting below warning while building signed apk

```
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find superclass or interface javax.annotation.processing.Processor    
library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
com.esafirm.imagepicker.features.imageloader.DefaultImageLoader: can't find referenced method 'com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target into(android.widget.ImageView)' in program class com.esafirm.imagepicker.features.imageloader.GlideRequest  
com.esafirm.imagepicker.features.imageloader.GlideRequest: can't find referenced method 'RequestBuilder(com.bumptech.glide.Glide,com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager,java.lang.Class)' in program class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder 
com.esafirm.imagepicker.features.imageloader.GlideRequests: can't find referenced method 'RequestManager(com.bumptech.glide.Glide,com.bumptech.glide.manager.Lifecycle,com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerTreeNode)' in program class com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient   
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBarLineScatterCandleBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBarLineScatterCandleBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.Sort    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.Sort    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineScatterCandleRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineScatterCandleRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults  
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults   
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion  
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment   
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind 
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Messager    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Processor   
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion  
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment   
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind 
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Messager    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic  
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment   
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion  
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment   
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror   
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement  
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror   
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement  
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror   
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement  
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Completion  
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement    
com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment    
com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory    
com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger   
com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory    
com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger   
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Basic 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Id    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.GeneratedValue    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.OneToOne  
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.ManyToOne 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Enumerated    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Version   
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Basic 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.ManyToOne 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.FetchType 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Enumerated    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.EnumType  
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Entity    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Table 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Entity    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Table 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Basic 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Id    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.GeneratedValue    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.OneToOne  
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.ManyToOne 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Enumerated    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Version   
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.EnumType  
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Entity    
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Table 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.FetchType 
com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.EnumType
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have enabled Proguard then you need to mention all required Progaurd changes in **proguard-rules.pro** file under app folder, You need to check the error and apply the **-dontwarn** , **-keepnames** , **-keepattributes** is required to mention for the particular libraries.

Comment: but I don't know where I have to apply -keep , -keepnames etc. and dontwarn, because when I put -dontwarn I am able to build signed apk but that is not installed error I am getting

Comment: what third party libraries are you using?

Comment: check the official page of the particular library you are using, they might have listed the proguard-rules